# How to remove javascript from query string parameter (Crosscripting)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a requirement to discard javascript code if it is passed through query string parameter in base 64 encoding. I want to strip all the javascript in parameter and leave the rest of the string. What is the best way to achieve this.

Input:

> www.xyz.com/pages/Load.aspx?new_url=/test.net/public/pages/SApps.aspx%3Flist%3DL&enc=true&title=Ij4gPHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgiaGVsbG8gZnJvbSBRQy4iKT wvc2NyaXB0PiA8aGVhZGVyOmNvbnRhaW50ZXIg

Title parameter when I Un Encode using following code in C#

```
 byte[] dataByte = Convert.FromBase64String(title);
                title= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataByte);
```

will result    "> `<script>alert("hello from QC.")</script> <header:containter`   which is a cross scripting issue.  I would like strip all the Javascript here ..

Comment: Check this out: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/preventing-javascript-injection-attacks-cs

Comment: I want to drop script elements from query string.

Comment: Show us how you get the values from the query string, and an example of what a "bad" input would be (and then what it would become).

Comment: So why does it matter if there is base64 encoded javascript? even if you write that directly to the browser it will not do anything.

Comment: Added Input above. The title parameter is used in html page and creating cross scripting issues.

Comment: But this would only cause an issue if you unencode the value. Show us where you are doing that, and what you want the output to be.

Comment: Added the input and output above  please advise now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the anti xss library to encode the query string or remove the script tags.

http://alldigitalblogs.net/2013/10/30/microsoft-security-library-antixss-library/he

The below method removes the script tags from the string, which can be used for page titles and html attributes.

Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(actualstring)

Comment: Link only answer are generally not answers. What happens if your link 404s?

Comment: I updated the comment with the specific API, which will remove the script tags.